# KDBG debugger run with redirected input

Tags: debugging, assembly, kdbg

Im trying to debug my AT&T assembly code with KDBG with redirected input for stdin but this doesnt work.

```
kdbg program1 < mydata.txt
```

tried also

```
cat mydata.txt | kdbg program1
```

any advices?

Comment: Do the redirection inside kdbg.

Comment: how? i guess u mean gdb (like gdb program1 and then run < input.txt, but it doesnt work like this in kdbg)

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant. As far as I can tell kdbg is a front-end to gdb so it should somehow work. If all else fails, attach to a shell process and `exec` your program there.

Answer (score 1):

Select *Execution->Arguments*, then put the following in the *Run program1 with these arguments* box:

```
< mydata.txt
```

I also strongly suggest that you switch to *Working Directory* in that dialog and fill in the directory. This ensures that the program is run in the correct directory and actually finds `mydata.txt`.

Comment: thanks! this worked perfectly! I've got one more problem, whenever I try to check memory during debug it says cannot access memory at (address - eg. 0x3), any ideas?:(

Comment: Not without further details. Anyway, it's a different question.